# How to smooth a curve in the way that updates the newest point?

Tags: smoothing

I am trying to smooth a curve like `x=x(t)` with t as time and x as plane vector; I have done some search work and simply known some names like Moving Average and Savitzky–Golay filter.

My problem is that the curve is ongoing and we can only get the position of the end point on the curve in each similar interval. However, the position we get is slightly different from the real position or in other words that it has a noise. If using the method like moving average to reduce the noise, like `x'[t]=(x[t+2]+x[t+1]+x[t]+x[t-1]+x[t-2])/5`, I won't get the refined point `x'[t]` which **might be more close to the point** `x[t]` until I get the point `x[t+2]`.

Is there any method that when get the newest end point `x[t]`, I get the refined point `x'[t]` **which is close to** `x[t]` using only previous points serial?

Comment: Any reason you can't do a moving average over previously obtained values? Like `x'(t) = (x(t) + x(t-1) + x(t-2) + x(t-3) + x(t-4))/5`?

Comment: The moving average equation you mentioned is a bit misleading in the context you've given. What it requires is 5 points which can then be averaged. Where you define t to be doesn't really matter. For exmple you could rewrite it as `x'(t)=(x(t-4)+x(t-3)+x(t-2)+x(t-1)+x(t))/5`. Written that way, it's a little more obvious that you don't need to wait for some time in the future, you just need 5 points which can be averaged.

Comment: Ok, let me back up a little. It was probably a bit too much to say that it doesn't matter where you define `t` to be, because obviously `x[t]` can't be both the equation you meantioned and the one mentioned in the first two comments. If all you're after though is smoothing, you can average the points you already have rather than waiting for more.

Comment: As a side note, when you're talking about `x` being discrete (a set of points) rather than continuous (the real number line), it's convention to use brackets (`[` and `]`) to denote an element of `x` rather than parenthesis (`(` and `)`). For example `x[t+2]` rather than `x(t+2)`.

Comment: Thanks for your question. Yes, I can do like x'[t] = (x[t] + x[t-1] + x[t-2]+ x[t-3] + x[t-4])/5, but image x[1:100] is a straight line, then x'[t=50] is still close to x[t=48] no matter what form you write. However, suppose I can rule out the noise by x'[t] = x[t] + x[t-1]- x[t-2] - x[t-3] + x[t-4], then the x'[t=50] is close to x[t=50].